# Error You might want to run 'apt-get -f install'

Tags: package-management, dpkg, libreoffice, dependencies

I have the next error when I try to install Google Chrome or LibreOffice or any software I want.

Error console:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.2.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I try to run this commands and nothing happens.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` before? It must finish without errors, or your package management might be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the --fix-missing parameter. As in:

```
sudo apt-get install -f --fix-missing
```

Comment: Fixed with this command:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common python3-uno libreoffice-*`

Comment: You should make your comment an answer and mark your question as solved.

Comment: How to mark as resolved?

Comment: First, you want to create a new answer, then you should be able to click on the check mark icon in to the left of your answer.